# Use custom WebSocket class in TypeScript for clients passed to WebSocket server events in "ws" package

Tags: typescript, websocket, ws

Using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) package and TypeScript, how might one make a WebSocket server pass instances of a custom WebSocket client class, instead of its own plain `WebSocket`, to any event handlers?

For example:

```
import { WebSocket, WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

class CustomWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    doSomething() {
        return true;
    }
}

class CustomWebSocketServer extends WebSocketServer {
    clients: Set<CustomWebSocket> = new Set();
}

const wss = new CustomWebSocketServer({ port: 1234 });

wss.on('connection', (clientSocket: CustomWebSocket) => {
    // Runtime error when connection event fires when client connects.
    // TypeError: clientSocket.doSomething is not a function
    clientSocket.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: the parameter passed into this function will be be a standard socket (not your class), typescript doesn't change what happens at runtime

Comment: Are you trying to do it in unit tests ?

Comment: @NalinRanjan no, this is app code

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I want to add a uuid and other properties with a new class extending WebSocket but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adapter on the client-side, you might be able to do something close, check this out... This implementation uses `WS`, `MONGODB adapter` and `PM2`.

```
const ip = require("ip");
const { createAdapter } = require("@socket.io/mongo-adapter");

const ioClient = require("socket.io-client");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const COLLECTION = "ws-io-adapter-events";

const socketClient = ioClient(
  `http://${ip.address()}:${process.env.PORT}/endpoint`
    );

const listenSockets = async io => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connection.createCollection(COLLECTION, {
      capped: true,
      size: 1e6,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // collection already exists
  }
  const mongoCollection = mongoose.connection.collection(COLLECTION);

  io.adapter(createAdapter(mongoCollection));

  const mainSocket = io.of("/endpoint");

  mainSocket.on("connection", socket => { //you can also pass your custom WS here
    socket.on("food:ready", (**custom_activity_goes_here_event_orfunc**) => {
      mainSocket.emit("food:ready", { data: **custom_activity_goes_here_event_orfunc** });
    });
  });
};
```